# Angular lifecycle components - different behavior depending on the environment

Tags: angular, web-deployment, angular-components

Edit:
@Alex – thank you for the question

Through debugging and cosole logging we found that there is a difference in the Angular lifecycle handling of the component that should show up.

The problem is that in one environnment(datails about them in PS if that might matter) the component that should show up after click is not refreshed right away – the ngOnChanges on the component is invoked only after second click anywhere else.
In our other environments everything works  fine and 4th step from the schema is executed automatically – immediate ChildComponent.ngOnChanges and the component is rendered

The idea is on the schema. We start in „step 1" by clicking the button.

[image: schema component lifecycle]

Below code is simplifed to show the meritum:

```
<div [class.layout-config-active]="openedRightPanel">
   <a  (click)="showHidePanel($event)">
     show component
   </a>
   ....
</div>

@Component (...)
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input() opened = false;
  @Output() openCloseClick: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   console.log('ChildComponent.ngOnChanges');   
  }
  
  showHidePanel(event) {    
    if (this.opened === true) {
      this.openCloseClick.emit(false);
    } else {
      this.openCloseClick.emit(true);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
  }  
}
```

In parent component:

```
<app-right-panel
      [opened]="childComponentActive" 
      (openCloseClick)="toggleComponent($event)">
</app-right-panel>
    
@Component(...)
export class ParentComponent {
(...)
    childComponentActive = false;
    
    toggleComponent($event: boolean) {      
        this.childComponentActive = $event;
    }   
}
```

PS. To give detailed information about environments that the app is served form:
Problematic environment:
new prod - k8s Azure service AKS

Environments where everything is fine:
local – dockerized application or served from minikube
dev + test – VM with minikube
prod – k8s AWS service EKS

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that through debugging you've found the click event works the same in both, it's the handling of the click which isn't working.  So how are you handling the click?

Comment: @Alex thank you, your questions made us decide to take a deeper look at the problem. We have edited the main post, read it again please.